# Exception behaviour in Python __set_name__

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-descriptors

I have a child class that is utilising Python 3.6+ `__set_name__` to ensure that owning classes have annotated the type of the field carrying the child class. If they haven't an exception is raised.

However, any exception raised is always caught by Python and a `RuntimeError` raised instead.

For instance:

```
class Child:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        raise Exception("OOPS!")

class Owner():
    child = Child()
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __set_name__
Exception: OOPS!

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Error calling __set_name__ on 'Child' instance 'child' in 'Owner'
```

This may well be expected behaviour (can't find a specific reference to `__set_name__` exceptions), but maybe also suggests the expectation is that `__set_name__` never suffers exception.

The behaviour I'm seeing isn't a problem, given an exception happens under the right conditions. However, it is tricky to test given I can't be sure the exception raised is the one my code raised.

Is there a better way of raising an exception that will lend itself to testing, or indeed a simple way to check the exception wrapped by the `RuntimeError` is indeed the one my code raised?

Comment: I really think this is an abuse of `__set_name__` which is part of the descriptor protocol... There are probably better ways to ensure annotation, like using a static analysis tool, like mypy

Comment: Note, I don't think that's being wrapped. Basically, I bet there's a big `try:... except Exception as e:` in `type` which simply raises this runtime error if anything that's part of the class creation throws an error. I can't find any official documentation on this, this may all be implementation details...

Comment: You should be able to access the `__cause__` of the RuntimeError to test whether it's the exception you raised.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - you could indeed consider this an abuse of `__set_name__`, except that nowhere is it documented exceptions shouldn't be raised... I'm looking for a pure Python solution, so don't have the option of adopting mypy at this stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, since you are getting the whole "The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception" that means that somewhere in `type` (the base metaclass) there is basically something to the effect of:

```
try:
    descr.__set_name__(A, 'attr')
except Exception as e:
    raise RuntimeError(msg) from e
```

That is, it's using `raise new_exception from original_exception`, so you should be able to introspect what the original exception was using the `__cause__` attribute:

So, observe:

```
In [1]: class Child:
   ...:     def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
   ...:         raise Exception("OOPS!")
   ...: try:
   ...:     class Owner():
   ...:         child = Child()
   ...: except RuntimeError as e:
   ...:     err = e
   ...:

In [2]: err
Out[2]: RuntimeError("Error calling __set_name__ on 'Child' instance 'child' in 'Owner'")

In [3]: err.__cause__
Out[3]: Exception('OOPS!')
```

Again, I don't think any of this is documented, so you may be relying on an implementation detail.

[Here is a link to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) which explains this in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to access the `__cause__` attribute on the wrapping exception to check whether this is happening due to your raised exception:

```
try:
    class Child:
        def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
            raise Exception("OOPS!")

    class Owner():
        child = Child()

except RuntimeError as rte:
    assert rte.__cause__.args[0] == "OOPS!"  # or a more appropriate check
```